# Как перенести команды в отдельный файл в python aiogram

Tags: python, функции, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть код с ботом для телеграмма, написанный на Aiogram. Не могу понять, как перенести команды бота в отдельный файл, а потом обращаться к ним

:Я решил проблему, сначала я отправляю переменную с ответом из функции (при помощи return) в основной файл, а потом в нём отправляю в телеграмм

Comment: Тему "модули и пакеты" изучали? Если нет, то сначала посмотрите её.

Comment: ну так я и пытался, всё равно не получается. Если перенести целиком с @dp.message_handler(content_types=['text']), тогда вообще не работает. Отдельно команды так же нельзя.

Comment: Советую, как минимум, разместить тут код того, что не получилось. Тогда хоть будет видно сообществу, что конкретно делали - выше шанс ответ нужный получить. Вообще странно вопрос звучит очень. Я не работал пока с Aiogram, но принципиально не могу понять, как что-то может не работать с файлом. Если не import, то хоть чтение из файла-то никто не отменял.

Comment: неважно, я решил проблему. Вместо самой функции отправки сообщения я сначала отправляю из функции сам ответ, а потом уже в основном коде отправляю этот ответ